# Spherical coordinates using ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, spherical-harmonics

In an exercise I am dealing with, where I consider a system resembling a 3D quantum harmonic oscillator, it says that the transition to spherical coordinates can now be made in the operator language.

If we have $a_x,a_y,a_z$ the ladder operators in the cartesian space, we can use:

$a_\theta=\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}(a_x+ia_y)$, $a_\phi=\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}(a_x-ia_y)$ and $a_z=a_z$

Now I don't understand how is this a transition to the spherical coordinates?
I know that in spherical coordinates for example:

$x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi$

By following the above relations, one can find:

$x=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(a_\theta^\dagger +a_\theta + a_\phi^\dagger + a_\phi)$

How is this the same as $x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi$? I am actually very confused. What do ladder operators have anything to do with representing a coordinate component from the cartesian basis to the spherical one

EDIT:
This is not a homework exercise or help me solve the exercise. There is nothing here that requires solving as it is already done. I want to understand the use of these ladder operators in the context of spherical basis representation.

It has nothing to do with asking for a solution of an exercise

Comment: I fear you are making notation up: did your instructor actually use θ and φ ? You are defining conventional tensors in the ***standard*** [spherical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis), and not polar coordinates,  but misnaming them sends you off to a freaky, unwarranted, tangent!

Comment: Once you toss the  θ and φ  nonsense, the spherical basis is self-explanatory, eqn (XII.86) of A Messiah's classic Quantum Mechanics, and most good textbooks...

Comment: The symbols $\theta$ and $\phi$ were used, and it was mentioned as a spherical basis representation

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Somebody conflated the spherical basis with spherical coordinates. Do you understand the point, nevertheless, names or not?

Comment: it was spherical coordinates**. And yes I do, basis uses the spherical harmonics (even though I don't see how that is mathematically of use) while the coordinates, is expressing cordinates as functions of $\rho,\phi,\theta$

Comment: OK, it's cool then. somebody goofed up. Declare $\theta\mapsto 1, ~ \phi\mapsto -1, ~z\mapsto 0$ and you are done. Don't look back. The spherical tensor basis is of *enormous* utility, as it underlies the ladder recursions.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Could I ask you something else, unrelated to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147977/discussion-between-imbaf-and-cosmas-zachos).

Comment: OK, and you could delete the question after I answer your unrelated one....